# Почему при загрузке фото с телефона развернутые?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня пользователи загружают аватарку. С компа все нормально, а вот когда с мобилки - фото развернутые. Это можно как то поправить?

Comment: Да *(10 символов нужно...)*

Comment: можете подсказать как?

Comment: Это легкий троллинг, что ничего не понятно и нужно как минимум посмотреть на свой вопрос в 3лице, или как максимум дополнить его

Comment: Погуглите - exif rotation

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что некоторые картинки не поворнуты в нужную ориентацию, а прописывают в метаданных, что их надо повернуть при отображении.

[Помогло вот это решение:](https://medium.com/thetiltblog/fixing-rotated-mobile-image-uploads-in-php-803bb96a852c)

```
$file = $request->file('image');
$image = \Image::make($file);
// perform orientation using intervention
$image->orientate();
$imageName = "image_name." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$destinationPath = public_path("/uploads");
// save image
$image->save($destinationPath . $imageName);
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.